# how to encrypt and decrypt string in vue 3

Tags: javascript, encryption, local-storage, session-storage

My id is stored in sessionStorage and I want to encrypt my id. how can I encrypt in Vue 3 and best way to secure my id?

```
sessionStorage.setItem('id', error.response.data.user.id)
```

this is my id and I want this to store in sessionStorage in encryption and then get decrypted id.

Comment: As it is more about `encryption` and `decryption`. Hence, removing `vue.js` tag.

Comment: You're likely trying to address a problem that doesn't exist. Consider explaining your concern.  Nothing is safe on client side. Basically, that a culprit has access to local storage is a really bad scenario, this most likely means that every secure piece of data on client side can be tampered one way or another

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cryptoJS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js) to achieve the `encryption` and `decryption`.

**Demo :**

```js
var id = document.getElementById("userId"),
    save = document.getElementById("save"),
    read = document.getElementById("read");
 
// Manage Save event
save.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    window.sessionStorage["userId"] = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(id.value, 'secret key');
}, true);

// Manage Read Event
read.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        let decryptedId = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(window.sessionStorage["userId"].toString(), 'secret key');
    document.getElementById('showId').innerHTML = decryptedId.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="userId" />
<input type="button" value="Save" id="save" />
<input type="button" value="Read" id="read" />

<p id="showId"></p>
```

Due to code snippet limitations its not able to accessing `window` object but you can take the reference.

Comment: It's also currently built in the browser itself, see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/

Comment: @Kokodoko Thanks for correcting. My bad I did not noticed. Why downvoted?  :)

Comment: It wasn't downvoted by me :)